# For a group morphism $G \rightarrow H$, give the image of the generators.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I have two group tables, both with order $24$. Now I have to write the images of the first generator as the second generator. The group elements are all letters, thus $G=\{A,B,C,...,V,W,X\}$ and the same holds for $H$, but the permutations of these elements are different.

In $G$, I have two generators, namely $L$ and $M$. Thus I can compute all other elements by these two. Now how do I find the images of these generators!? Are they, by definition, mapped into the generators of $H$ or does this not hold?

If this question is too vague, let me know, I find it hard to word it in an understanding way.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the mapping is or is not an isomorphism. Is this needed?

Comment: This depends on what you really want to show. I thought, you want to decide whether or not the two groups are "the same", i.e., isomorphic.

Comment: Just to clarify, in addition to the given group tables of the two groups $G$ and $H$, are you also given the group morphism $f : G \to H$? So you are asking how to find $f(L)$ and $f(M)$?

Comment: If so, then the problem is that $f$ is not unique. Given $G$ and $H$, there can be many different homomorphisms $f : G \to H$, and you have not told us any further information about $f$. For example $f$ could be the trivial homomorphism, in which case $f(L)$ and $f(M)$ are both equal to the identity element of $H$. On the other hand, $f$ could be some nontrivial homomorphism, in case case at least one of $f(L)$ or $f(M)$ must not be equal to the identity.

Comment: @LeeMosher, these considerations are exactly what I needed. Just these thoughts already help me out, thanks